# Saving data to array more efficent code

Tags: java, arrays

I am very new to Android Studio and have written a Product Scanner app which stores data in an array, it does work but I know this block of code is very long and would like suggestions on how I can make it more efficient, I would like to rewrite this so that I don't end up with two big blocks, one to update and one to add, I have exhausted my research on this.

My array is called products and currentProduct is a class item

```
public void SavetoArray() {

    //Get Time & Date
    GetTodaysDate();
    //check ALL field before saving

    //if (CurrentDate == null) CurrentDate = todayDateTimeString;

    //if indexpoint at end of array then we need to use ADD action to ADD ARRAY RECORD TO EOF
    if(indexpoint == products.size()){

    }
    if (indexpoint == products.size()) {
        products.add(indexpoint + UPC_FIELD_OFFSET, currentProduct.getmUPC());    
        products.add(indexpoint + DESC_FIELD_OFFSET, currentProduct.getmName());    
        products.add(indexpoint + UNITHEIGHT_FIELD_OFFSET, currentProduct.getmUnitHeight());    
        products.add(indexpoint + UNITWIDTH_FIELD_OFFSET, currentProduct.getmUnitWidth());    
        products.add(indexpoint + UNITDEPTH_FIELD_OFFSET, currentProduct.getmUnitDepth());    
        products.add(indexpoint + TRAYHEIGHT_FIELD_OFFSET, currentProduct.getmTrayHeight());    
        products.add(indexpoint + TRAYWIDTH_FIELD_OFFSET, currentProduct.getmTrayWidth());
        products.add(indexpoint + TRAYDEPTH_FIELD_OFFSET, currentProduct.getmTrayDepth());
        products.add(indexpoint + TRAYNUMH_FIELD_OFFSET, currentProduct.getmTrayNumHigh());
        products.add(indexpoint + TRAYNUMW_FIELD_OFFSET, currentProduct.getmTrayNumWide());
        products.add(indexpoint + TRAYNUMD_FIELD_OFFSET, currentProduct.getmTrayNumDeep());
        products.add(indexpoint + TRAYTOTALNUM_FIELD_OFFSET, currentProduct.getmTrayTotalNum());
        products.add(indexpoint + STATUS_FIELD_OFFSET, currentProduct.getmStatus());
        products.add(indexpoint + DATE_FIELD_OFFSET, currentProduct.getmDate());

        // this just checks we are adding a row to arraylist
        Toast.makeText(this, "Products on file" + products.size() / RecordFieldCount, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {

        //if indexpoint not end of array then we need to use set action = UPDATE ARRAY RECORD
        products.set(indexpoint + UPC_FIELD_OFFSET, currentProduct.getmUPC());
        products.set(indexpoint + DESC_FIELD_OFFSET,currentProduct.getmName());
        products.set(indexpoint + UNITHEIGHT_FIELD_OFFSET, currentProduct.getmUnitHeight());
        products.set(indexpoint + UNITWIDTH_FIELD_OFFSET, currentProduct.getmUnitWidth());
        products.set(indexpoint + UNITDEPTH_FIELD_OFFSET, currentProduct.getmUnitDepth());
        products.set(indexpoint + TRAYHEIGHT_FIELD_OFFSET, currentProduct.getmTrayHeight());
        products.set(indexpoint + TRAYWIDTH_FIELD_OFFSET, currentProduct.getmTrayWidth());
        products.set(indexpoint + TRAYDEPTH_FIELD_OFFSET, currentProduct.getmTrayDepth());
        products.set(indexpoint + TRAYNUMH_FIELD_OFFSET, currentProduct.getmTrayNumHigh());
        products.set(indexpoint + TRAYNUMW_FIELD_OFFSET, currentProduct.getmTrayNumWide());
        products.set(indexpoint + TRAYNUMD_FIELD_OFFSET, currentProduct.getmTrayNumDeep());
        products.set(indexpoint + TRAYTOTALNUM_FIELD_OFFSET, currentProduct.getmTrayTotalNum());
        products.set(indexpoint + STATUS_FIELD_OFFSET, currentProduct.getmStatus());
        products.set(indexpoint + DATE_FIELD_OFFSET, currentProduct.getmDate());

    }
}
```

Comment: I actually don't understand the code. Why don't you just add the product instance to a List?

Comment: First point, there are no arrays here: it seems you use a `List`. Second point, Java is an Object Oriented Programming language. Why don't you use objects instead of spreading each property of your object inside a `List`? That's a kind of weird design: objects are used to give structure to data, and here, you remove this structure and flatten everything in a `List`.

Comment: Please excuse me i am a beginner, I receive 7k-20k of record data in csv format, I read that into products array the app does not use any lists, it consists of two activities. A product is scanned using an Android Laser scanner, if found a view with unit data is populated from the array, and the operator can also capture more information into EditText boxes in the second activity, after all records are finished the app writes the csv file back to file for uploading into PC program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of reading the product into an array and writing to a csv file, consider using Objects.  This is an efficient and intuitive way of storing the information so that it can be easily accessed in the future.

Here's Oracle's documentation on classes/objects to get you rolling.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

Comment: I think I'm to old for Java, I understand things like sequential searching and yes I know about SQL Lite and perhaps should have setup a database, but I'm lost with objects,if I have 7000 products do I read in from CSV and create 7000 objects and how do I manage and find the one I want? Where do object reside.

Comment: An object could be thought of as a more versatile variable. The objects reside in memory just like variables, so creating that many wouldn't be a problem

Comment: Would I be on the right track if I re-wrote my whole import routine to read in one record from the csv file assign that to a New Product class and then put that product class in a list?, that way I could search for a Product then act on the class gets/sets easier.

Comment: Yes that sounds like a very object-oriented way to tackle this

Comment: I have now written code to import CSV file and build a list of Product Instances and can do a search and return a product, I have Products Instances with names such as @3f6802 and I can read the data from them using

productslist.get(i).getmUPC() etc which I can use to update the EditText in my app

My Question: When I find the correct product I take it I can set values directly in that iproduct Instance if  user changed values in the EditText directly as well or do I need to copy it to a current product class?, what is a good way to ensure I reference the correct Product Instance.

Comment: THanks you all for your help, I went with Jeff's guidance in the end and used a List of Product Class instances, this has made the code easier to read and has reduced my lines of code from 970 to under 700 and I learnt a lot as well, thank you, problem solved by team effort.

Comment: Hey Dennis glad to hear this helped! Also glad to see you wen't outside your comfort zone and it worked out well.

Answer (score 0):

As i can see, it's more a matter of code design than anything else. What you can do is to redesign your code.

Create a map to display the type of offset and its value (DATE_FIELD_OFFSET, STATUS_FIELD_OFFSET, ...).

Instead of using the currentProduct.getXX(), create a **factory**. Lets call it **CurrentProductFactory**.

You create a method called **setUpdate(int gap, int index, int retrievedValue)**. This method switches from a set or an update depending of the value of indexpoint.

```
public class CurrentProductFactory {    
// We use the offset name to return the needed method
    public int get(String offset){
        switch(offset){
            case "DATE_FIELD_OFFSET":getmDate();
            break;
            case "STATUS_FIELD_OFFSET": getmStatus()
            break;
            }
    public int getmDate() {
    }
    public int getmStatus() {
    }
}
    // A map to manage your offsets
    TreeMap<String,Integer> offsets = new TreeMap<>();
    offsets.put("DATE_FIELD_OFFSET",DATE_FIELD_OFFSET);

// The method to embody the set and the update alternatively
    public void setUpdate(int gap, int index, int retrievedValue) {
        if(gap != 0)set(index, retrievedValue);
        else add(index, retrievedValue);
    }
```

Your code becomes :

```
//Get Time & Date
    GetTodaysDate();

    int gap = indexpoint-products.size();

    for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : offsets.entrySet()) {
        String offset = entry.getKey();
        Integer offset_value = entry.getValue();
        products.setUpdate(gap,indexpoint+offset_value,CurrentProductFactory.get(offset));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, This look exactly what I wanted to try and do, I know what I am doing seems clunky but its worked for over a year now but I want to make it more robust, I will test this in a sample program, I just need to get it clear in my head.

Comment: You're welcome. If you face issues, feel free to revert to me.

Comment: Don't forget that you could make the get() function of CurrentProductFactory a static one, to be more flexible and to avoid creating a lot of useless objects.